# How to reset a form after submission using Controller As syntax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, typescript

After adding an object via a form, I would like to reset the form so the user can add another.  I've tried $setPristine() but can't figure out the syntax. As of now, I have just set the location path back to the same page, but that of course doesn't reset anything. Also wondering if $setPristine is the correct way. Here is my save function.

```
    export class AddCarController {
    public newCar;
    public save() {
        this.carService.save(this.newCar).then(() => { this.$location.path('/addCarPage') });
    }
    constructor(
        private carService: MyApp.Services.CarService,
        private $location: angular.ILocationService
    ) { }

}
```

Comment: If you have created javascript in a controller then you can simply set the object as -

$scope.car = {}

This would reset the model in UI.

Comment: thanks!  Unfortunately, I don't know how to use the $scope syntax.

Comment: Did you create any javascript object? If yes then simply reset it as : $scope.newCar = {};

Comment: thanks!  Got me in the right direction.  I needed to reset it as : this.newCar = {};

Comment: Can you please upvote my answer since this has worked for you?

Comment: first edit your answer to the format as I used it, as I explicitly mentioned I am using "controller as" syntax, and not $scope syntax.  Any answer involving $scope is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

In angular Your can create model in **just in html**  and also in **controller** or **on both places**

> If you have created Model in html

```
$scope.newCar = {} //this will empty whole ui model object
```

> If you have created Model In Javascript Controller

```
$scope.newCar = new carModel() //this will create new car object with default values , if you have model in controller
```

> Navigate Back And Forth - Not Recommended